# Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Match failing

Tags: powershell, ip-address, subnet

So I am using this:

```
$IPA = (Get-NetIPAddress | Where-Object InterfaceAlias -eq "MyPortName").IPv4Address
```

and then I want to use the following to grab the Subnet Mask for that IP:

```
$IPInfo = (Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object IPAddress -Match $IPA)
```

Followed by:

```
$SubMask = $IPInfo.IPSubnet[0]
```

But this fails with $IPInfo being blank.  If I hard code the IPAddress it works:

```
$IPInfo = (Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object IPAddress -Match 10.45.22.100)
```

But the port IP will always be different.  Why is it not taking the $IPA as a match parameter?

EDIT: The IP Address being reported has both the IPv4 and IPv6 which is why I am trying to do -Match against the IPv4.

Comment: I am checking now if this is your issue but `-match` supports regex so any meta characters there could be causing a conflict. If that is for an exact match just use `-eq`instead. Could be getting more than one result as well. What does `$ipa` look like when you print it to console?

Comment: `$IPA.GetType().FullName` show `System.Object[]` by chance?

Comment: When I do just $IPA in the console it shows 10.45.22.100 but when I do $IPA.GetType().Full name it does show System.Object[] .  

Also I cannot do -eq because the IP is listed like this:

IPAddress   {10.45.22.100, 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we have discovered in comments you are getting an array returned for your `$IPA`. It looks fine in console as PowerShell unrolls the array to display all elements. Since there is only one it was misleading.

```
((Get-NetIPAddress | Where-Object InterfaceAlias -eq "Local Area Connection").IPv4Address).gettype().fullname
System.Object[]
```

Likely it was trying to match "System.Object[]" which is why you did not get the result you wanted.

Few ways around this. A simple one would be to always return the `-First` result in your query.

```
(Get-NetIPAddress | Where-Object InterfaceAlias -eq "Local Area Connection").IPv4Address | select -first 1).gettype().fullname
```

So just use `| select -first 1` and you should get the results you expect.

---

I caution the use of `-match` here. Understand that `-match` and `-replace` support regex pattern strings. So if you have regex meta characters in your strings you can get unexpected results.

Comment: Nice.  Thanks!  Worked perfectly.  :)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because $IPA is really an array of objects.
When you run `Get-NetIPAddress | Where-Object InterfaceAlias -eq "MyPortName"` it returns an array of CIM instances of type MSFT_NetIPAddress.
When you ask for `IPv4Address` member by running `$IPA = (Get-NetIPAddress | Where-Object InterfaceAlias -eq "MyPortName").IPv4Address` the array is still there but the elements of the array that don't have IPv4Address are not shown.
Take a look at the following example.

```
$NetIPAddresses = (Get-NetIPAddress | where {$_.InterfaceAlias -eq "Ethernet" -and $_.AddressFamily -eq "IPv4"})
foreach ($NetIPAddress in $NetIPAddresses) {
   $IPA = $NetIPAddress.IPv4Address
   $IPInfo = (Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object IPAddress -Match $IPA)
   $IPInfo.IPSubnet[0]
}
```

This will show subnet mask for each IPv4 address on the given interface.